# How to allow Chrome popups from certain IP network ranges?

Tags: google-chrome, popups

As per default Chrome is blocking popups. This is of course the best approach but I would really like to allow popups from our trusted internal IP ranges (we use IPs for some stuff - not DNS). This could e.g. be `10.0.0.0/8` or alike.

If I insert this single IP entry in to my registry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\PopupsAllowedForUrls`:

```
Value: 1
Type: REG_SZ
Data: https://10.0.0.1/
```

.. then it will allow popups from this specific single IP address but I have too many IP addresses to handle this manually in registry, so how can I allow the full 10-net range?

I also know that I can insert this global policy in to the registry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome`:

```
Value: DefaultPopupsSetting
Type: REG_DWORD
Data: 1
```

.. which will default allow all popups but this is not what I want as I only want to allow it for internal stuff (and 10-net is not routed to the internet).

Is it possible to whitelist an IP range for Google Chrome popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though this is not the answer I had hoped for, then it is the answer for my own question/problem - this seems impossible :-/

This is from a Chrome documentation, [Enterprise policy URL pattern format](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/url-patterns/?_ga=2.263678158.394486487.1623246351-1689557047.1622721922):

> Instead of a domain, an IPv4 address in the form “a.b.c.d” can be
> used. While the rules for schemes, ports and paths remain the same as
> for domain URLs, **wildcards cannot be used at all for IP addresses**.